# Ko ObservableArray object not updating Via WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have an observable array Object that which is generated like this:

```
 self.SelectedVariable = ko.observableArray();
    self.VarUpdate = function (data) {
        $.getJSON("/api/Variable/" + ko.toJS(data.VarID), ko.toJS(data.VarID), function (Result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i++) {
                element = Result[i];
                self.SelectedVariable({ VariableID: ko.observable(element.VariableID), VariableDateLastUpdated: ko.observable(element.VariableDateLastUpdated), VariableName: ko.observable(element.VariableName), VariableDescription: ko.observable(element.VariableDescription), VariableValue: ko.observable(element.VariableValue), VariableType: ko.observable(element.VariableType) });
            };
        });
```

When I try to pass the **SelectedVariable** object to my WebAPI method using this AJAX call

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Variable?Del=0",
            data: { vardata: ko.toJS(self.SelectedVariable) },
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (Result) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

, all the related object shows null on all the fields.
[image]
I have tried almost every combination to get the **SelectedVariable** Object to parse correctly to my WebAPI method:

```
data: { vardata: ko.toJS(self.SelectedVariable) },

data: { vardata: ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable) },

data: { vardata: JSON.Stringify(self.SelectedVariable) },

data: { vardata: self.SelectedVariable },
```

and have tried to manually decrypt JSON object on WebAPI side using:

```
    public void Put([FromUri] int Del, [FromBody]string vardata)
    {

        Variables vari = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Variables>(vardata);

        var Item = (from c in TMIRE.Variables
                    where c.VariableID == vari.VariableID
                    select c).First();

        if (Del == 0)
        {
            Item.VariableDateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            Item.VariableName = vari.VariableName;
            Item.VariableDescription = vari.VariableDescription;
            Item.VariableValue = vari.VariableValue;
            Item.VariableType = vari.VariableType;
```

And It is still null value.

Any Advice would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Changed my WebAPI method to reflect as follows:

```
 public void Put([FromUri] int Del, IEnumerable<Variables> vardata)
    {
        var Item = (from c in TMIRE.Variables
                    where c.VariableID == vardata.Select(x => x.VariableID).First()
                    select c).First();
        if (Del == 0)
        {
            Item.VariableDateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            vardata.Select(a => Item.VariableName = a.VariableName);
            vardata.Select(b => Item.VariableDescription = b.VariableDescription);
            vardata.Select(c => Item.VariableValue = c.VariableValue);
            vardata.Select(d => Item.VariableType = d.VariableType);
        }
```

and now the **vardata** object gets the value but all objects within are null 
[image]
My Ajax method looks like this:

```
 alert(ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Variable?Del=0",
            contenttype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: "=" + ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable()),
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (Result) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

The alert gives me this response

[image]

The Variables Class

```
 public class Variables
{
    public int VariableID { get; set; }
    public DateTime VarialbeDateLastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
    public string VariableDescription { get; set; }
    public string VariableValue { get; set; }
    public string VariableType { get; set; }

}
```

**Working Code**

By using this Ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Variable?Del=0",
            contenttype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: "=" + ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable),
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (Result) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

and then using [Newtonsoft](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to deserialize the object on WebAPI using this method:

```
public void Put([FromUri] int Del, [FromBody]string vardata)
    {

        Variables vari = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Variables>(vardata.Substring(1, vardata.Length-2));

        var Item = (from c in TMIRE.Variables
                    where c.VariableID == vari.VariableID
                    select c).First();

        if (Del == 0)
        {
            Item.VariableDateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            Item.VariableName = vari.VariableName;
            Item.VariableDescription = vari.VariableDescription;
            Item.VariableValue = vari.VariableValue;
            Item.VariableType = vari.VariableType;
        }
        else
        {
            Item.VariableDateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            Item.VariableActive = false;
        }

        TMIRE.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I Got it to work

Comment: before you hit the ajax call, have you used Chrome dev tools to check the values of `self.SelectedVariable`?

Comment: I have, and the object generates correctly on client side. I also added and alert to my Ajax call to see if the JSON generates correctly. And it does. Here is the JSON I get From Client Side `{
  "VariableID": 4,
  "VariableName": "Admin EMail Address",
  "VariableDescription": "The Email Account for Administration Panel.",
  "VariableValue": "no_reply@themindisright.com",
  "VariableType": "String"
}`

Comment: shouldn't the WebAPI be expecting `IEnumerable<Variables> vardate`, since you're building a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this Ajax call

```
       $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Variable?Del=0",
        contenttype: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: "=" + ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable),
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "JSON",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (Result) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

and then using Newtonsoft to deserialize the object on WebAPI using this method:

```
public void Put([FromUri] int Del, [FromBody]string vardata)
{

    Variables vari = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Variables>(vardata.Substring(1, vardata.Length-2));

    var Item = (from c in TMIRE.Variables
                where c.VariableID == vari.VariableID
                select c).First();

    if (Del == 0)
    {
        Item.VariableDateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        Item.VariableName = vari.VariableName;
        Item.VariableDescription = vari.VariableDescription;
        Item.VariableValue = vari.VariableValue;
        Item.VariableType = vari.VariableType;
    }
    else
    {
        Item.VariableDateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        Item.VariableActive = false;
    }

    TMIRE.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
public void Put([FromUri] int Del, IEnumerable<Variables> vardate){}
```

Since you're building a collection on the client `self.SelectedVariable = ko.observableArray();`, you will need the API to receive an `IEnumerable`.

In the Ajax call, I think it would be best to use:

```
data: { vardata: ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable) }
```

as this will give you a *JSON* representation of the collection.

Also, on the KO side, shouldn't you be pushing elements into the collection? `self.SelectedVariable.push({...});` or you will end up with only the final result.

Comment: Now its = 0. Changed my put method to reflect like this `public void Put([FromUri] int Del, [FromBody]IEnumerable<Variables> vardata)` and ajax to `data: { vardata: ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable) },`

Comment: I have added an update section to the original question

Comment: can you add the code for the class `Variables` just the properties?

Comment: Added to bottom of Question. Keep in mind I am using Database First methodology and Not Code first.

Comment: I made a hasty response, disregard it.  You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change assignment to this:

```
    self.SelectedVariable = ko.observableArray();
    self.VarUpdate = function (data) {
        $.getJSON("/api/Variable/" + ko.toJS(data.VarID), ko.toJS(data.VarID), function (Result) {
            var selection = self.SelectedVariable;
            for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i++) {
                var element = Result[i];
                selection.push(element);
            };
        });
```

Then, Change the ajax method to convert to json:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Variable?Del=0",
        content-type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: "=" + JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable)),
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "JSON",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (Result) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Also try removing `[FromBody]`.

```
public void Put([FromUri] int Del, IEnumerable<Variables> vardata)
{
    ...
}
```

It looks like making the serialized objects in vardata as ko.observable objects is confusing mvc serialization for the parameters.

different data assignments to attempt:

`data: "=" + JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable))`

`data: "=" + JSON.stringify(self.SelectedVariable())`

`data: "=" + self.SelectedVariable()`

`data: "=" + $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable))`

Comment: Changed it exactly ass suggested. vardata is still = 0

Comment: Also try adding content-type, changing assignment to data as noted in my recent edit, and removing frombody.

Comment: It Finally parsed the object, but all the values within **SelectedVariable** are null.

Comment: Update your original post with the values of `self.SelectedVariable()` in the client before `$.ajax` and the most up-to-date-code that you have for your mvc service.  I will change my response according to your edit.

Comment: The latest Update on the question is up. Check the UPDATE Section for the latest code

Comment: updated my ajax method.  removed koObservable invocation to handle on self.SelectedVariable.

Comment: Now it is a matter of just getting the data serialized properly.  Edited ajax method with a silly suggestion to hopefully solve this.

Comment: Nope. Still the same.

Comment: Added some other suggestions down below on my main post

Comment: I finally got it to freaking work! See working code section Thanks for all the help. If you ever find yourself in South-Africa, Drinks are on me!

Answer (score 0):

What you're passing self.SelectedVariable isn't an array. Should you not be calling it just an observable? Otherwise, you need to be adding your results with self.SelectedVariable.push(resultObject).

Comment: the vardata is obviously not parsing correctly...thing is, you are converting self.SelectedVariable to JSON, but your vardata is still a JS object...I would recomment you try just passing the object...eg data: ko.toJSON(self.SelectedVariable()

Comment: Ok I understand, but not to sure about how to implement correctly?